# Retrieve only HTTP response instead of debug info

Tags: python, http, https, header, urllib2

I've the request below which works fine but it returns sent request and server full response. How can I just get response body ?

```
req = urllib2.Request('some url here', data = '')
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPSHandler(debuglevel = 1))
req = opener.open(req)
reply = req.read()
req.close()
print reply
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That extra information is explicitly requested with `debuglevel=1`. You can simply remove that, or even the whole opener definition, like this:

```
import urllib2
print (urllib2.urlopen('https://phihag.de/').read())
```